# C++ & vimspector & -exec -enable-pretty-printing

Tags: vim, vimspector

Currently I have to enter `-exec -enable-pretty-printing` into *vimspector* debugger command line (debugging C++ code using *vscode-cpptools*) to see `std::string` as a "string" rather than as a STL container. Could you advice me how to modify my *.vimspector.json* to run the command automatically on *vimspector* launch? I tried to google it out but without success... My current *.vimspector.json* looks like this.

```
{
  "configurations": {
    "Vim - run a test": {
      "adapter": "vscode-cpptools",
      "configuration": {
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main",
        "args": [
            "-enable-pretty-printing"
        ],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "environment": [
          { "name": "VIMRUNTIME", "value": "${workspaceRoot}" }
        ],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "logging": {
          "engineLogging": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thx,

Michal

PS: The mentioning `-enable-pretty-printing` as argument in *.json* file does not work.

Comment: Use  the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: I can debug the code. It only annoys me having to manually enter ```-exec -enable-pretty-printing``` into the debugger console every time I start debugging.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I have installed *vscode* and had a look at its configuration files. It seems that the following *.vimspector.json* file does what I want.

```
{
  "configurations": {
    "FinMat": {
      "adapter": "vscode-cpptools",
      "configuration": {
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "environment": [
          { "name": "VIMRUNTIME", "value": "${workspaceRoot}" }
        ],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "logging": {
          "engineLogging": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```